# Application is getting stuck at hibernate txOracle.commit();

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, postgresql

```
try {
        sessionOracle = BaseDAO.getHibernateSession().openSession();
        sessionPostgres = BaseDAOgis.getHibernateSession().openSession();
        int id = 0;
        JSONArray jaRoute = new JSONArray();
       for (int i = 0; i < dataHolder.size(); i++) {
             JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();



            try{
            jo.put("routeNo", (int) list.get(0));
            jo.put("routeName", list.get(1).toString());
            jo.put("stopSequenceID", (int) list.get(2));
            jo.put("stopID", (int) list.get(3));
            jo.put("stopName", list.get(4).toString());
            jo.put("lat", (double) list.get(5));
            jo.put("lon", (double) list.get(6));
            System.out.println(jo.length() + "" +cellStoreVector.size());
            if(jo.length()!=cellStoreVector.size())
            {
                System.out.println(jo.length() + "if" +cellStoreVector.size());
                joOutput.put("success", true);
                joOutput.put("error", true);
                joOutput.put("size", false);
                return joOutput;    
            }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("EXCEWs");
                System.out.println(e);
                joOutput.put("success", true);
                joOutput.put("error", true);
                joOutput.put("size", false);
                return joOutput;
            }
            jaRoute.put(jo);
        }
        System.out.println("DB");
        txPostgres = sessionPostgres.beginTransaction();
        txOracle= sessionOracle.beginTransaction();


         for (int i = 0; i < jaRoute.length(); i++) {
            direction = "U";
            JSONObject first = jaRoute.getJSONObject(i);
            routeNo = first.getString("routeNo");
            System.out.println();
            int no = Integer.parseInt(routeNo);
            routeName = first.getString("routeName");
            stopSequenceID = first.getString("stopSequenceID");
            stopID = first.getString("stopID");
            stopName = first.getString("stopName");
            lat = first.getString("lat");
            lon = first.getString("lon");
        if(i < jaRoute.length() - 1)
            second = jaRoute.getJSONObject(i + 1);
            System.out.println("id"+ id);
            if(Integer.parseInt(first.getString("routeNo"))!= id){
                try{
                String sqlRouteMaster = "insert into route_master(route_id, route_name, direction, route_status, route_no, ROUTE_EFCTV_FROM_DT,Source_stop_id,dest_stop_id,ROUTE_TYPE,city_operational) "
                        + "values('"
                        + routeNo
                        + "','"
                        + routeName
                        + "','"
                        + direction1
                        + "','"
                        + routeStatus
                        + "','"
                        + routeName.trim().substring(0, 9)
                        + "',now(),'"+1038+"','"+1039+"','"+37+"','"+false+"')";
                String sqlMRoute="insert into m_route(route_id, route_name, direction, route_status, route_no, ROUTE_EFCTV_FROM_DT,source_stop_id, dest_stop_id,ROUTE_TYPE,CITY_TYPE) "
                        + "values('"
                        + routeNo
                        + "','"
                        + routeName
                        + "','"
                        + direction
                        + "','"
                        + routeStatus
                        + "','"
                        + routeName.trim().substring(0, 9)
                        + "', current_timestamp,'"+1038+"','"+1039+"','"+37+"','"+97+"')";

                int list4=sessionPostgres.createSQLQuery(sqlRouteMaster)
                        .executeUpdate();
                System.out.println(list4);
                int list5=sessionOracle.createSQLQuery(sqlMRoute).executeUpdate();
                System.out.println(list5);
       }catch(Exception ii){
       }finally{}
       if(Integer.parseInt(second.getString("routeNo")) == id || id == 0){
                double endLat = Double.parseDouble(second
                        .getString("lat"));
                double endLon = Double.parseDouble(second
                        .getString("lon"));
                theGeom = getMultiLineString(startLat, startLon,
                        endLat, endLon);
      if (theGeom.length() > 0) {
                System.out.println("rout");
                sqlRouteDetails = "insert into route_details(route_seq_no,route_id,stop_seq_no,stop_id,location,lat,lon,the_geom,stop_type_id,REF_DISTANCE,REF_TIME,STOP_TIME)"
                        + " values('"
                        + routSeqNo
                        + "','"
                        + routeNo
                        + "','"
                        + stopSequenceID
                        + "','"
                        + stopID
                        + "','"
                        + stopName
                        + "','"
                        + lat
                        + "','"
                        + lon
                        + "',ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('"
                        + theGeom
                        + "'),4326),'"
                        + stopTypeId
                        + "','"
                        + refDistance
                        + "','" + refTime + "','" + stopTime + "')";
            } else {
                System.out.println(id);
                sqlRouteDetails = "insert into route_details(route_seq_no,route_id,stop_seq_no,stop_id,location,lat,lon,stop_type_id,REF_DISTANCE,REF_TIME,STOP_TIME)"
                        + " values('"
                        + routSeqNo
                        + "','"
                        + routeNo
                        + "','"
                        + stopSequenceID
                        + "','"
                        + stopID
                        + "','"
                        + stopName + "','" + lat + "','" + lon + "','"+stopTypeId+"','"+refDistance+"','"+refTime+"','"+stopTime+"')";
            }
            id=Integer.parseInt(first.getString("routeNo"));
            String sqlMRouteDtl="insert into m_route_dtl(route_seq_no,route_id, stop_seq_no, stop_id,stop_type_id,REF_DISTANCE,REF_TIME,STOP_TIME) "
                    + "values('"+mRouteSql+"','"+routeNo+"','"+stopSequenceID+"','"+stopID+"','"+stopTypeId+"','"+refDistance+"','"+refTime+"','"+stopTime+"')";
            sessionPostgres.createSQLQuery(sqlRouteDetails).executeUpdate();
            sessionOracle.createSQLQuery(sqlMRouteDtl).executeUpdate();
            routSeqNo++;
        }
        //
        txOracle.commit();
        //
        txPostgres.commit();
        joOutput.put("success", true);
        joOutput.put("error", false);
    } catch (Exception i) {
        i.printStackTrace();
        //
        txPostgres.rollback();
        //
        txOracle.rollback();
        joOutput.put("success", false);
        joOutput.put("error", false);
    } finally {
        try {
            sessionPostgres.close();
            sessionOracle.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return joOutput;
    }
}
```

forthe first time or twice , appLicaton is running fine but if we are trying For next time it is stuck at

```
Hibernate: insert into m_route(route_id, route_name, direction, route_status, route_no, ROUTE_EFCTV_FROM_DT,source_stop_id, dest_stop_id,ROUTE_TYPE,CITY_TYPE) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

And again we are restarting Oracle db then  again same thing. once or twice running and stuck.
please help me.
Thanks in advance.
I could not able to find the problem. Why its locking/ postgres and oracle.

> route_master and route_details are Postgres tables and
>   m_route and m_route_dtl
>   are Oracle tables

Comment: You're going to have to diagnose the problem.  Do you see the session in Oracle?  What is that session waiting on?  Were I to guess, I would guess that you have multiple sessions trying to insert the same data into a column or set of columns that has a unique/ primary key constraint and one of those sessions never commits its change causing the second session to be blocked waiting on the lock.  But that's a wild guess since we don't have much information.

Comment: while I am trying the same code in some other machine its working fine as now.

Comment: >select sid, serial#, username, command, lockwait, osuser from v$session where lockwait is not null

Comment: >select sql_text from v$sqltext where (address,hash_value) in (select sql_address,sql_hash_value from v$session where lockwait is not null) order by address, hash_value, piece

Comment: >SELECT SESSION_ID, name
FROM DBA_DML_LOCKS
WHERE NAME = 'M_ROUTE'; here sessions are created and one is getting locked.

Answer (score 1):

First of all why you are using plain sql when have Hibernate in the project? its just not efficient.

Second based on code you provided you opening new hibernate session each time, try initilize it just once.

Finally can you log on admin account on oracle/postgres and check what is actually going on when apllication gets stuck ?

Comment: No I was not opening new hibernate session each time, just only once at top